# if statement doesn't work with the simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement

I'm trying to make a button that at first click it says "alabama" and the second click "alaska". I'm using the if statement, but when I'm running the simulator, "Alaska" comes at the first click. what have I done wrong?

```
- (IBAction)button1:(id)sender {
    hellolabel.text = @"Alabama";

    if([hellolabel.text isEqual:@"Alabama"])
        hellolabel.text = @"Alaska";
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `if([hellolabel.text isEqualToString:@"Alabama"])` ?

Comment: Yes, the same thing happened!

Comment: `isEqual` should work here, though it's not as safe as `isEqualToString`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is not arranged properly.

It actually sets both states (Alabama, and then Alaska), but because it runs so fast, you don't see it set the Alabama.

Because the:

```
hellolabel.text = @"Alabama";
```

comes before the `if` statement, it will set the `hellolabel.text` to Alabama. But because the `if` statement is also contained within the same action, it will proceed to run it (as the code here runs sequentially), without stopping. And since you just set the `hellolabel.text` to Alabama, your `if` statement will set it to Alaska, seeing that it does meet the criteria that it is checking for (`if([hellolabel.text isEqualToString:@"Alabama"])`).

The correct code so that it will check properly, would be like this:

```
- (IBAction)button1:(id)sender {

    if([hellolabel.text isEqualToString:@"Alabama"])
    {
        hellolabel.text = @"Alaska";
    }
    else
    {
        hellolabel.text = @"Alabama";
    }
}
```

Comment: when I use "else{" there comes an error saying "expected identifier or ("

Comment: What do you mean by that? I did miss a closing brace at the end of the code, so try copying it again.

Comment: It works now! Thank you very much, I'm still learning this so I appreciate all the help! :)